# Symfony DomCrawler: Find element with specific attribute value

Tags: php, dom, symfony, html-parsing

I'm using the DomCrawler component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

I'd like to, using the CSS like syntax, get an element with a specific attribute value.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$link = $crawler->filter('#product a[data-type="bla"]');
```

This seems to work, as the following returns 1:

```
echo count($link);
```

However, I can never not filter further than this. I can not do:

```
$link->filter('img')->attr('src');
```

This results in the following error message:

```
The current node list is empty.
```

However, I know for certain that it isn't.

I've tried the syntax on other elements and it's always the same. I am doing something wrong or is this not possible (with css like syntax, not xpath)

Comment: What is the output for `echo count($link->filter('img'));`? If 0, I guess you don't have a img element as a child of your a. That's the reason of `The current node list is empty.`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I can not follow your problem. Using the current development versions (and also 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 versions) of the ***two*** software libraries *dom-crawler* and [*css-selector*](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/css-selector), the example code you provided works just fine considering the following example HTML:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

// require dependencies here    

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
        <div id="product">
            <a data-type="bla">
                <img src="OK">
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$link = $crawler->filter('#product a[data-type="bla"]');

echo var_dump(count($link));

var_dump($link->filter('img')->attr('src'));
```

As you can see this is exactly your code (only a little different but essentially not), which gives the following output verbatim:

```
int(1)
string(2) "OK"
```

The first output line is the *`count()`* and the second is the src attribute value.

Have you run composer update? Have you double-checked the input?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must apologize. The input was indeed incorrect. It was transformed via javascript and I was checking via Safari, which does not have a simple view source method any more, leading to incorrect assumptions of the data.

Comment: @Wesley: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4325736?start=0&tstart=0 <- you have enabled the developer menu?